# Does Kinesis guarantee delivery?

Tags: amazon-web-services, messaging, amazon-kinesis

I am searching the documentation of Kinesis Data Streams but I can't find a clear statement like

> Kinesis guarantees at least once delivery

From the producer side I expect that a message sent, gets propagated to more than one nodes (something like Kafka's ack=all)
From the consumer side I am expecting something equivalent to Kafka commit offset on successful processing from the consumer, or something like Google Cloud's Pub/Sub message acknowledgement.

Is there a submit message guarantee for Kinesis?
Is there a processing guarantee for Kinesis (mark message as read only if processed and acknowledged that it was processed)

Comment: If yo are after Kafka functionality, why not use AWS MSK?

Comment: I prefer as close to serverless as possible. I know MSK fixes the pain points of Zookeeper and Kafka but I want something more seamless from Kafka.

Comment: I think there is some confusion here. Kinesis is not pub/sub type system. In AWS this is provided by SNS. So there are no any acknowledgment of processing or messages being read by consumers.

Comment: Got you. So it's more like store the messages on the kinesis nodes. Then once you spin up the consumer the consumer will read all the messages it requests and it is the consumers responsibility to keep track the messages it processed or not.

Comment: Yes. What's more you can't delete messages from kinesis. They stay there until they expire, so they can be read many times by many consumers at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the documentation consumers from Kinesisread the entire data from the Stream.
Thus consumers are responsible to commit their history and pick up from where they left.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/building-consumers.html

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, if you are really after server-less approach, why not use [Lambda Event source mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html) to consume Kinesis messages?

- Lambda/AWS will poll for messages, batch them up and call our lambda function for a batch of records(batch size as small as 1).
- If Lambda function returns success, batch will be committed and function will be called for next batch.
- If Lambda function returns failure, batch can be retired.
- Unlike Kafka consumers where we need to handle retrying exceptions separately with another kafka topic or a database, to keep consumer moving forward, AWS Lambda supports asynchronous retires as well.

For a simple use case, Kinesis + Lambda is as good as Kafka + Consumer.